# Why I am not able to record desktop/windows application using Vugen 12.60?

Tags: loadrunner, vugen

When I try to record desktop/windows application via Vugen 12.60, application launching via recording, events are increasing, but once recording is stopped, script is generating **empty** Action.c block.

Need help in this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What protocol is your desktop application using to connect to the next upstream architectural component?

What Programming API is your Desktop application using to generate a message to your next upstream architectural component?

Are you running your desktop application via Citrix or Terminal server as a published application, which is running on another computer but displayed on your computer?

Have you considered recording Winsock (see first few buffers of data.ws)  as a discovery mechanism to understand the well known ports, IP addressses, and services that your desktop application is communicating with?

Comment: Migrated Load Runner(Vugen) to the latest version 2021_R2 and tried recording, which fixed my recording issue.

Answer (score 0):

Migrated Load Runner(Vugen) to the latest version 2021_R2 and tried recording, which fixed my recording issue.